# Find an example such that $\tau$ is a stopping time and $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ and $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ differ on $\{\tau = \infty\}$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, examples-counterexamples, stopping-times

I need to find an example such that the following is true:

$\tau$ is a stopping time and $\mathcal{F}$ is a filtration defined on $\mathbb{R}_+$. Let $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ denote the stopped $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ and $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ differ on $\{\tau = \infty\}$.

Comment: In that case, with the definitions I have, $\mathcal{F}_\tau$ and $\mathcal{F}_\infty$ agree trivially, since $\{\tau = \infty\}$ is the empty set.

Comment: $\mathcal{F}_\infty = \sigma\{ \mathcal{F}_t : t \in \mathbb{R}_+\}$.

Comment: Similarly, if the underlying $\sigma$-algebra is $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{F}_\tau = \{ A \in \mathcal{A} : A \cap \{ \tau \leq t\} \in \mathcal{F}_t$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}_+\}$.

Comment: Sorry, so the other definition is two sigma algebras $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ agree on a set $A$ if $\mathcal{F} \cap A = \mathcal{G} \cap A$.

Comment: ok, I did not read the question carefully enough.

Comment: Final piece of notation: $\mathcal{F} \cap A = \{ F \cap A : F \in \mathcal{F} \}$. So if $A$ is the empty set, this trivially holds.

Comment: What do you mean by "differ on $\{\tau = \infty\}$"?

Comment: That they do not agree on the set $\{\tau = \infty\}$. This is using the definition of "two sigma algebras agreeing on a set" I gave above.

Comment: Any progress on this question?